# How to Route /About to /Home/About

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am just getting started with ASP.NET MVC and it's great! However, I don't quite understand setting up routes.

How do I route ~/About to ~/Home/About?

/Views/Home/About.aspx

I would like to be able to access it with
**/Home/About**
or just
**/About**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to explicity setup a route for it, you can do something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute( 
            "AboutRoute", 
            "About", 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "About" }  // Parameter defaults 
    );
```

I think thats what you want to do? I.e. have /About handled by the home controller?

The default route (as below) handles /Home/About

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: that was easy ;-) thanks!. I should have asked how to set it up with wildcards. so /Home/ContactUs goes to ContactUs

Comment: @Brian - not sure I fully get what you mean, do you mean you want any route in home controller to be accessed by /{action} rather than /{controller}/{action}? I wouldn't recommend it, it would mean you couldnt have the default route as above ("{controller}/{action}/{id}"). Easier to just specify the specific routes like for /About above for the home controller actions you want.

Comment: The problem with this is both /home/about and /about will route to the content - so you have duplicated content on your site (bad practice - and bad for SEO).

Answer (score 7):

In response to your comment on RM's answer - you don't actually need wildcards for that. Just do

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AllToHomeController",
    "{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });
```

Note, however, that you need to place this route at the very end of your route table (and you'll have to delete the default route), as this will catch *every* url that comes in.

You can use Phil Haack's [Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to verify that your routes pick up urls as you expect.