# How do I map the URL example.com/root/login to just example.com/login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, controller, url-routing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to map Home/Action/id to just action/id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832202/how-to-map-home-action-id-to-just-action-id)

I have a Views folder called "root"
Inside it is a view called "login.aspx".

[image]

I have a Controller called "rootController.cs".

[image]

I have an ActionResult called login()
It returns View("login").

When I run my app... To get to the login page I have to see an ugly url www.example.com/root/login

[image]

I would like it to say www.example.com/login.

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: ////

So far:

[image]

EDIT: ////

Solved:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to map Home/Action/id to just action/id?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2832202)

Comment: If you remove the `root/`, how would you disambiguate actions in other controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your  `MvcApplication` class (by default it is in `Global.asax.cs` file) and add the following code to the `RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` function:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "Login", // Route name
      "login", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "root", action = "login" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: Just create a route. This is the correct solution.

Comment: I have placed this underneath the "Default" Route name... When i visit www.example.com/login it errors. Anything obvious I am doing wrong? (see last image added)

Comment: @JamesT, I've eddited the post.. I could make some error in url there...

Comment: That doesn't seem to be why. In fact i tried that too my self hehe. Any more ideas. I wish i was more... able to get the gist, but Until I have a working example for myself, I'm just not gnna get it. Thanks for your ongoing help.

Comment: Ah i see what the problem is... its my Default route that comes with default app. I remove.. my index page doesnt show but i can resolve with second route.

Comment: See last image.. working perfectly. Cheers.