# How to hide the home controller path in action links

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Using the out of the box MVC application the action links under the Home controller are rendered as follows

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")  > /
@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home") > /Home/About
```

How do i make all action links that falls into the HomeController to hide the "Home" in the link paths.

e.g

```
@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")     > /About
@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home") > /Contact
@Html.ActionLink("Sitemap", "Sitemap", "Home") > /Sitemap
@Html.ActionLink("Terms", "Terms", "Home")     > /Terms
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can set the controller in your route part and remove it from the url. Something like this:

```
  routes.MapRoute("", "/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596990/how-to-route-about-to-home-about) also.

Answer (score 1):

You can create different routes in the RouteConfig class as followed:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AboutUs",
                url: "about-us",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "AboutUs" }
            );
```

This way, when the URL is /about-us it's going to call the AboutUs action in Home controller.